# Generated .crt file from text

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, https

I bought a SSL certificate and got these Text files.

-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIHhjCCBm6gAwIBAgIQBBHZG2IHaYx3EGHHgy1+GzANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFADBZ
.
.
.
STrB0u+/i8hZL9KBhMXFxhdUdcaze3xSlX6xDL+TQymtIY7KuLJa/XU9++bYBBb7
++7PCC9+Mxz/cA==
-----END CERTIFICATE-----

-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIJQwIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASCCS0wggkpAgEAAoICAQDYBIFobN
.
iSSIxSIje5XiU4BPCd9Os4hbyWYFBbDwj+g=
-----END CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----

-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----
MIIExjCCAq4CAQAwgYAxEzARBgNVBAMMCmNsZW1lbnMuc2sxFTATBgNVBA
.
iSSIxSIje5XiU4BPCd9Os4hbyWYFBbDwj+g=
-----END CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----

-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIFUTCCBDmgAwIBAgIQB5g2A63jmQghnKAMJ7yKbDANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQ
.
yWQlk9VDV296EI/kQOJNLVEkJ54P
-----END CERTIFICATE-----

I'm Not Sure how to make an .crt file Out of it

Comment: There is no need to convert - this is already in `PEM` format, so just rename to `.crt`